# What is WPF is all about?

Tags: wpf

Could some one let me know what is Windows Presentation Framework is all about?
And how this is different form existing C# UI development?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Ravi Naik.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897945/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wpf-over-winforms/897951#897951

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked before. Take a look at:

[What are the benefits of using WPF over Windows Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897945/what-are-the-benefits-of-using-wpf-over-winforms/897951#897951)

[WPF vs  Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713193/wpf-v-s-winform/713249#713249)